# Passing arrays to function

Tags: c, arrays, function

```
#include <stdio.h>
float average(float age[]);

int main()​
{
    float avg, age[] = { 23.4, 55, 22.6, 3, 40.5, 18 };
    avg = average(age); /* Only name of array is passed as       argument. */
    printf("Average age=%.2f", avg);
    return 0;
}

float average(float age[])
{
    int i;
    float avg, sum = 0.0;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
   {
        sum += age[i];
   }
avg = (sum / 6);
return avg;
}
```

If I follow the same convention ,
Would it be correct to write

```
int main()
{
    int a[]={1,2,3};
    int a1[]=a;
    ....
}
```

Can I assign the address of a into a1here

Or would this be correct

```
int main()
{
int a[]={1,2,3};
int a1[];
a1=a;
...
}
```

The second one is probably wrong since I have already created an array a1 with 0 space alloted

If we can pass it to a function like that 
Why can't we use it directly like in first case I gave

Comment: ...... have you tried?

Comment: No, you cannot assign one array to another. Instead, you must use a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, you cannot assign arrays to one another. Instead, you must use a pointer which points to the address of the first element in your array. Here is an example which shows this:

```
/* My array */
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};

/* pointer which points to the first element of arr[] */
int *ptr = &arr[0];

/* prints out contents of pointer */
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0]; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", ptr[i]);
}

/* Outputs: 
   1
   2 
   3
   4
*/
```